# Выберите или выберете?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно написать: выберЕте или выбирИте в следующем предложении:
"Вы сможете пополнить лицевой счет только после того, как на странице торгового каталога выберите страну доставки".

Answer (score 23):

В Вашем примере глагол "выберете" употреблен в форме будущего времени изъявительного наклонения. Пишу Е, так как глагол первого спряжения. В данном случае глагол с ударным окончанием: берЁте - выберете (приставка Вы перетягивает ударение, приставка спряжения не меняет). В русском языке есть и глагол "выберИте", но это глагол повелительного наклонения с суффиксом И  (берИ-выберИ-выберИте). Сравните: ВыберИте книгу. Когда выберЕте, подходИте...