# ВыберИте, ВыберЕте или Выбирите?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Фраза: Выберите вариант ответа....
Как правильно написать: ВыберИте или ВыберЕте?

Comment: Возможно, дубликат вопроса https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/4641/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5

Answer (score 2):

Повелительное наклонение множ. ч. от *выбрать* — ***выберите***.